# request.getUserPrincipal() got null

Tags: java, security, spring, jakarta-ee

User successfully authenticated but after authentication when I go to next controller I got `request.getUserPrincipal()` null. I am using websphere 7 and my application is in spring mvc.

```
   System.out.println("subject.getPrincipals(): " + subject.getPrincipals());

   WSSubject.setRunAsSubject(subject);
```

After authentication in login controller subject.getPrincipals() returns principal but when I go to next controller I got `request.getUserPrincipal()` null.

**web.xml**

```
<security-role>
    <role-name>Administrator</role-name>
</security-role>

<security-constraint>
    <display-name>manager_Service</display-name>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>manageservice</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/manageServiceList.htm</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>Administrator</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
    <user-data-constraint>
        <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
    </user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

**application.xml**

```
<security-role>
    <role-name>Administrator</role-name>
</security-role>
```

**ibm-application-bnd.xml**

```
<security-role name="Administrator">
    <group name="Administrator" />
</security-role>
```

User belongs to Administrator group. All my deployment descriptors are set up well. Any idea where I am getting mistake?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Creating and configuring custom JAAS login module solves problem. See Listing 4 [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/techjournal/0508_benantar/0508_benantar.html)

Don't know what was the problem with my previous code.

Answer (score 3):

It seams that you are guarding only one url `/manageServiceList.htm` so if the user access an other url then there should be no principal at all.

Comment: There will be other resources. But this is not my problem. There should be principal whether I access protected resource or unprotected.

Comment: That is may what you want, but not the way it works: When I remember right, you must have to guard the resource to get an request with populate principal. But of course it is legal to guard the resources whit no restriction (allow all).

Comment: See my question: "After authentication in login controller subject.getPrincipals() returns principal but when I go to next controller I got request.getUserPrincipal() null". What is the problem? Why I got it null?

Comment: @imran tariq: what do you mean be next controller, an controller that is mapped to an other (not protected) url?

Comment: next controller mean. Any controller after login. Problem is server container is not updating itself that user is authenticated and thus returns principal null.