# How to use J2eePreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter and a custom authentication provider?

Tags: spring-security, websphere

I want my Spring application to try two pre-authentication methods (*Siteminder* and *Java EE container authentication*).

1. If either of these filters locates a username - I want to check that username against my database of users and assign roles based on what I see in the database. (I have an implementation of AuthenticationUserDetailsService, which does that for me.)
2. If not - show a login page to the user. Check the credentials they enter in the form against my database of users.

The Siteminder integration is working. The login form is working too. **My problem is with the Java EE pre-authentication. It never kicks in.**

My applicationContext-security.xml:

```
<!-- HTTP security configurations -->
<sec:http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
    <sec:form-login login-processing-url="/resources/j_spring_security_check" always-use-default-target="true" default-target-url="/" login-page="/login"
        authentication-failure-url="/login?login_error=t" />
    <sec:logout logout-url="/resources/j_spring_security_logout" />
    <sec:access-denied-handler error-page="/accessDenied" />
    <sec:remember-me user-service-ref="customUserDetailsService" token-validity-seconds="86400" key="OptiVLM-VaultBalance" />
    <sec:custom-filter position="PRE_AUTH_FILTER" ref="siteminderFilter"/>
    <sec:custom-filter after="PRE_AUTH_FILTER" ref="jeePreAuthenticatedFilter"/>

    <!-- various intercept-url elements here, skipped for brevity -->
</sec:http>

<!-- Authentication Manager -->
<sec:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <!-- J2EE container pre-authentication or Siteminder -->
    <sec:authentication-provider ref="customPreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider" />
    <!-- Default provider -->
    <sec:authentication-provider user-service-ref="customUserDetailsService" />
</sec:authentication-manager>

<!-- Siteminder pre-authentication -->
<bean id="siteminderFilter" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.RequestHeaderAuthenticationFilter">
    <property name="principalRequestHeader" value="SM_USER" />
    <property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager" />
    <property name="exceptionIfHeaderMissing" value="false" />
</bean>

<!-- J2EE pre-authentication -->
<bean id="jeePreAuthenticatedFilter" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.j2ee.J2eePreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter">
    <property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager" />
</bean>

<!-- Custom pre-authentication provider -->
<bean id="customPreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider">
    <property name="preAuthenticatedUserDetailsService" ref="customAuthenticationUserDetailsService" />
</bean>
```

I have Java 2 security enabled in Websphere, and I am logged in as 'admin5'. (I have a user with this username in my user database.) But when I access the application, there is never a call to the 'customAuthenticationUserDetailsService' bean to verify the username. I know this, because 'customAuthenticationUserDetailsService' does extensive logging which clearly shows what it is doing. When I am using the Siteminder pre-authentication - the 'customAuthenticationUserDetailsService' works just fine, I get some trace output in the log. But not for the J2EE authentication...

My guess is that one of these things is happening:

a) Java EE pre-authentication filter is not locating the username, so it never calls the authentication manager

b) Java EE pre-authentication filter works fine, but my custom authentication provider is never called by the authentication manager for some reason

*By the way, the default authentication provider, which uses 'customUserDetailsService' does not kick in either. Again, I can tell that because there is no output from 'customUserDetailsService' in the log.*

**Can you advise on what could be the problem here? If not a solution, then a suggestion on how to approach this would be greatly appreciated.**

Comment: J2eePreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter is actually a very simple class. It just calls `HttpServletRequest.getUserPrincipal()` to get the current user. I would check check that this is being set correctly by websphere by just calling the method yourself in a filter, for example, when you are logged in through the container.

Comment: thank you, Luke. i will try that tomorrow

Comment: yes, HttpServletRequest.getUserPrincipal() returns null... i think this may be because I have no security constraints in my web.xml. That's the feeling I get from reading about situations when the null is returned.

Comment: this question is very useful to me. Thanks!!

Comment: I realize this is 5 years later, but do you by any chance have an example of your `customAuthenticationUserDetailService` and `customPreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider` beans?  I'm running into a similar configuration need and not entirely sure how to set this configuration up.

Comment: unfortunately, i do not anymore

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK, I figured this out. The problem is that even though I had J2EE security setup in Websphere and was authenticated, my web.xml contained **no security constraints**. Because of this, Websphere was not supplying the principal for my requests. This is apparently an intentional feature. If you are not accessing a protected URL, you should not need the pre-authentication information.

To overcome this, I **added a security constraint** to my web.xml, which allowed ALL users to access the resources. Effectively, the resources were not secured, but still - there was a constraint now.

This is it:

```
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>All areas</web-resource-name>
            <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint>
            <role-name>*</role-name>
        </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

This tricks the Websphere into filling in the user principal information in the request.

Thank you @Ralph for his comments on this this question: [request.getUserPrincipal() got null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7795012/request-getuserprincipal-got-null)

Comment: btw, does anyone know if I am doing the 'mention' correctly? i thought it was going to turn into a link to the user's profile...