# How to connect spring security configuration with IBM Liberty Profile basicRegistry

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, websphere-liberty

I have a running springmvc with spring security web application running on IBM Liberty profile. I use java config to set all up (and no web.xml).

Extending the class WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter, I set up the simple list of users as follows:

```
@Autowired
public void configureGlobalSecurity(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
 auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("bill").password("123456").roles("USER");
}
```

I do not want user information in my code, so I want to move the user registry to the server.xml of the IBM Liberty profile server.

```
<basicRegistry>
    <user name="bill" password="123456"/>
</basicRegistry>
```

How can I configure this?

Extra information I use a multimodule maven project, with an ear and a war module. So in the server.xml the last line is the

```
<enterpriseApplication id="hellospringEAR" location="hellospringEAR-00.00.0001-SNAPSHOT.ear" name="hellospringEAR"/>
```

Any hint or advice is much appreciated.

Comment: Check this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9847324/3701228), it describes how to configure Java EE integration with Spring security (talks about the site minder, but principals are the same, you want users from the server).

Comment: ever figured this out?  Can you share?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use Spring Security's support for container managed security (that's the jee() method)

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SecurityConfig.class);

@Autowired
private ApplicationProperties appProperties;

@Override
protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and().httpBasic();

    if (appProperties.isContainerManaged()) {
        LOGGER.info("using container managed");
        http.jee();
    }
    http.csrf().disable()
            .logout()
            .permitAll();
}
}
```

More details here:
[Roles / Authorities not working in Websphere Liberty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41271467/roles-authorities-not-working-in-websphere-liberty)

Comment: Thanks David ... but I get null for the principal. And I'm still trying to grasp the whole filter chain in spring.

Comment: Can you provide me with the code of you LibertyPreAuthenticatedWebAuthenticatedDetailsSource? How I hook it up in de securityConfig class and I struggle to find the correct maven repository/dependency for the com.ibm.websphere.security library.